# How to efficiently check if a Key Value pair exists in a Javascript "dictionary" object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, dictionary

Given:

```
        var dic = {1: 11, 2: 22}
```

How to test if (1, 11) exists?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of the time very simply, with

```
if (dic[1] === 11)
```

with one caveat: if the value you are looking for is `undefined` this will not do because it cannot distinguish between `{ 1: undefined }` and just `{}`. In that case you need the more verbose test

```
if ('1' in dic && dic[1] === undefined)
```

Answer (score 18):

If you need to check both if the key exists, and has a value, the below piece of code would work best:

```
function hasKeySetTo(obj,key,value)
{
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key]==value;
}
```

It only returns true if `obj` has a key called `key` and that key has `value` as its value.

Comment: What if `value` is falsy and the object does really have it?

Comment: @Jon I completely overlooked that, but I edited the function to account for it.

Answer (score 0):

In [Nushorn Java script engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) you can do also

```js
if (dic.0) print('tested for null and key 0 exist')
```

Comment: Thanks @LastTribunal for pointing out that it needed clarification of what/where - Nushorn Java script engine instead of just Nushor :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try "in" keyword**

```js
let dic = {1: 11, 2: 22};
if(1 in dic) console.log("found");
if(!(3 in dic)) console.log("not found");
```

Comment: How to test if (1, 11) exists?